# Translate an element along one axis while keeping the other as is

Tags: html, css

I have a HTML element which has `transform: translateX(some_percent)` applied.

Is there a way to animate this element along the y-axis without changing the translation along the x-axis?

//EDIT

To clarify, `some_percent` is unknown and there is no way of accessing it.

I am interested if this is possible in general, without changing the html. It seems to me as if a translation is always a vector of (x,y) with [translateY](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/translateY) just being a shorthand for `translate(0,y)`.

Comment: Wrap it in another element and apply the y-axis translation to the parent element.

Comment: Oh... That edit was really necessary!

Comment: How do you set the unknown `some_percent` value?

Comment: @JordiNebot I set this inside the css. I mean I know how to make this work in general, but I am interested if this can work _without_ changing/knowing the `some_percent`. So _just_ changing the y-axis.

Comment: Well, I guess you can't *just* changing the y-axis, because either you use `transform: translate(x, y)` or `transform: translateX(x) translateY(y)` you'll need the `x` value. Anyway, I proposed a *solution* using custom properties in my answer below.

Comment: Yes, I suppose that is true. Reading through my comment I get the feeling that you could have read this as a little _"passive-aggressive"_ . It was not intended that way, I just wanted to bring the point across that I am wondering if you can set x or y independently of each other. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: Don't worry @Philiiiiiipp :) I didn't read it that way. About setting `x` and `y` independently I guess the only way is using an outter wrapper as in @Santhos' answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a wrapping element and animate that:

**HTML**

```
<div id="outter">
  <div id="img">

  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#img {
  width: 250px;
  height: 150px;
  background-image: url('http://placehold.it/250x150');
  transform: translateX(22%);
}

#outter {
  transform: translateY(40%);
}
```

**JS**

```
var transY = 10;
var times = 0;
var x = function() {
  if (times > 5) {
    times = 0;
  }

    document.getElementById("outter").style.transform = 'translateY(' + times * transY + '%)';
  times++;
  setTimeout(x, 1000);
};

x();
```

https://jsfiddle.net/nayk1uLz/2/

Answer (score 0):

the first parameter is the X axis and the second the Y ;).

```
transform: translate(50%, 50%);
```

Here is a jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/fugfswmt/

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution proposal using a CSS [Custom Property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_variables) (a.k.a CSS Variable):

```css
div {
  width: 5rem;
  height: 5rem;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 5rem;
  transition: transform 300ms;
}

#red {
  background-color: red;
  --some_percent: 24%; /* Default value */
  transform: translateX(var(--some_percent)); /* Unknown value */
}

#red.translate-y {
  transform: translateX(var(--some_percent)) translateY(50%); /* Any value */
}
```

```html
<!-- Adding a click event just for demo purposes -->
<div id="red" style="--some_percent: 42%" onclick="this.classList.toggle('translate-y')">Click Me</div>
```

I'm guessing that if your `some_percent` value is unknown, you're setting it inline (after some server-side calculation, maybe?), so a pure CSS solution could be to set this unknown value as a CSS variable inline and use it as a constant on `translateX` and adjust `translateY` to whatever value you need.